# Animate Height To Fit As DOM Elements Are Added to Container

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to animate changes in height of a container element as the height of the content changes. I'm trying :

```
.container {
  height: auto
  background: #eee
  -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Then calling:

```
$('.container').html('...');
```

However, each time the container snaps automatically. If I call:

```
$('.container').height(400);
```

The animation occurs. However, I'm not sure the size of the contents. Any thoughts on how to trigger it when changing the content?

Comment: Have you tried the resize event?  `element.onresize = function() {...}`

Comment: @Steve How can this be used for a CSS transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by calculating the height of the inner contents and explicitly setting using height() on the parent. This works, but is a bit of a pain, as the height needs to be recalculated on window resizes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing a trick but I've been doing the same thing this evening.

You can't animate to an auto height (even min-height) or the transition breaks.

You can use max-height: 0; as the start point.

The only thing stopping me was the height issue - luckily my elements are fixed height.

- Forgot to mention - percentages should be fine to animate to, I meant a fixed number.